# turn off ZSH glob expansion in function arguments in interactive shell

Tags: zsh, glob

When I find myself in times of arithmetic trouble¹, I like to simply calculate on my shell

```
> echo $(( 3**4 - 2/7*5 ))
```

which of course works beautifully. However, I find that it's too much typing, so I defined

```
function §()
    echo $(( $@ ))
```

which allows me to

```
> § '3**4 - 2/7*5'
```

but not

```
> § 3**4 - 2/7*5
```

Because zsh tells me it could find no matches (or worse, expands filenames if there are some matches).

How can I tell the zsh shell that I want it to *not* interpret things entered as arguments to a function as globs?

I don't want to do something like

```
> enter_non_glob_mode
> 3**4 - 2/7*5
> back_to_normal_mode
```

because instead of that, I could as well start `dc`, `python`…

---

<sup>¹Mother Euler speaks to me, wispering words of wisdom, power of e... SCNR.</sup>

Comment: Just out curiosity: Why does it work to define a function without curly braces? I can see that it does work, but the man page says: _function word ... [ () ] [ term ] { list } ... The  body of the function is the **list** between the { and }._, (and there is no explanation about the meaning of _term_).

Comment: That is a very valid question. I often find the zsh man pages to be satisfactory when you want to look up built-ins, but insufficient on the language details, and the official zsh programmer's tutorial to be not that great. Anyways, from any other language with `{}` code blocks: A curly-braces-encapsulated block is just as good as a single statement. In C, that's even explicitly called a "compound statement". In ZSH, they probably forgot to mention that it's actually `function foo() statement`, where statement can be anything, including a compound statement.

Comment: The function without braces is an [alternate form](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Alternate-Forms-For-Complex-Commands) of the function syntax. (You can also leave out the function keyword.)

Comment: @ak2 ah, true! Nice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `noglob` modifier.

```
% noglob § 3**4 - 2/7*5
81
```

To avoid having to type `noglob` each time, use an alias to insert the modifier. (You can't put `noglob` inside the function, as pathname expansion will have already taken place before the body is evaluated.)

```
% alias §='noglob §'
% § 3**4 - 2/7*5
81
```

Comment: excellent solution! I didn't realize `alias` applies prior to globbing